Adding multiple IAM tools in Angular/.Net Core application
We are developing a product using Angular 17 and .NET Core 6 Web API. For authorization and authentication, we plan to integrate external IAM tools such as Okta, Azure AD, etc. Given that each client may use different IAM tools, what is the best approach to integrate multiple IAM tools into our application while minimizing duplicate code?

Well, based on your description, use a modular approach leveraging OpenID Connect (OIDC) and OAuth 2.0. In the backend, create an abstraction layer for authentication using interfaces and a factory pattern to manage different IAM services, configured via appsettings.json. Implement middleware to handle authentication and populate user claims.

Apart from that, on the frontend, use an OIDC client library and develop a dynamic authentication service that configures and handles authentication flows based on the selected IAM provider, with settings stored in Angular environment files. This approach ensures minimal code duplication and maintains flexibility and scalability.

Thanks for your response. Is there any sample resource available for a reference?

How to do that in angular ? Can we register two different IAMs in angular using a dynamic service ?

We should configure that in backend service.

BackendService? So, its done at the .Net API layer? But, how do we add these IAM configurations in angular side and implement its respective functionalities? For eg. AuthGuard ? This may be different for Okta & AzureAD.

Well, you can store IAM configurations like client ID, issuer URL, and scope in Angular’s environment files. Then, create a dynamic authentication service that reads these settings and configures the OidcSecurityService from the angular-auth-oidc-client library. This service enables login, logout, and authentication status checks.
